# Weight matrix definition in weighted least square method

Tags: regression, least-squares

On page 220 of [Kutner](http://books.google.nl/books/about/Applied_linear_regression_models.html?id=3_AlAQAAIAAJ&redir_esc=y), the author defined the weight matrix in weighted least square method as $\sigma_i^2 = \sigma^2 / w_i$, which is problematic because $\sigma^2$ is unknown. Even more confusing is that the estimate $MSE_w$ involves $w_i$ which is in turn defined by $\sigma^2$, forming a circular argument.

Am I missing something here?

[image]

Comment: You seem to be misreading the formulas, which are inconsistent with your description.  The weight matrix $W$ does not involve $\sigma^2$ and is known by the analyst; the formula for $MSE_w$ is explicitly independent of $\sigma^2$.

Comment: Yeah, but $w_i$ depends on $\sigma^2$. And I don't even know what $\sigma^2$ stands for since the variances are not constant, hence the weighting.

Comment: Precisely how does this book define $w_i$? (It's not accessible through your link.)  Normally the $w_i$ are specified by the analyst independently of the data.  Sometimes they are guessed or estimated from the data, but then they are *still* treated as if they were independently specified by the analyst. In the passage shown, one would normally understand $\sigma_i^2$ as being *given* along with the data, not estimated from the data.

Comment: It's kind of confusing, the words seem to define $w_i$, but the formula goes the other way around.

Comment: I cannot find a definition of $w_i$ other than the one I uploaded here. It looks familiar to the inverse-variance weighting.

Comment: I will, in approximately 2 and a half hours from now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps they way it is stated is confusing, but the set up is nevertheless correct (and estimable!). I assume that by "weighted least squares" the author describes the situation where the error covariance matrix has different elements in the diagonal, but it is still a diagonal matrix (i.e. no-correlation, just heteroskedasticity, otherwise we should be talking about generalized LS). But the critical point here, as @whuber essentially says, is that we always specify these diagonal terms *as a function of the data*, together with an unknown scaling factor $\sigma^2$. Namely, the specification is 
$$E(uu'|X) = \text{diag}\Big (\sigma_1^2,...,\sigma_n^2\Big)=\sigma^2V(X) = \sigma^2\text{diag}\Big (v_1(X),...,v_n(X)\Big)$$
and the $v$'s are calculable functions of the data. So we *specify* $$\sigma_i^2 = \sigma^2v_i(X) $$
Then the weights are chosen as $w_i=\frac{1}  {v_i(X)}$ and inserting in the previous relation we obtain
$$\sigma_i^2 = \frac {\sigma^2} {w_i}$$
which is the relation shown in the book. How we determine the functional form of the $v$-functions? Either the form of heteroskedasticity is a priori known, or we simply guess, usually choosing among various functional forms that have been examined in the literature.

**ADDENDUM: FUNCTIONAL FORMS FOR THE WEIGHTS**
These may come from more or less formal economic analysis. For example, in studies of firm profits, the size of the firm has been shown to correlate with the variance of the error term. In that case, the variance of each observation may be specified as $\sigma_i^2 = \sigma^2x_{ik}^2 $ where $x_{ik}$ is the regressor representing the size of the firm involved. It is also possible to introduce unknown parameters and specify
$\sigma_i^2 = \sigma^2\Big[\mathbf x_{i}'\alpha\Big]^2 $.
In such a case you can either estimate with a two-step estimator, or apply maximum likelihood. Standard econometric texts will provide you with more.

Comment: I see, first you specify $v_i$, then get $w_i$ by inverse, then estimate $\sigma^2$ by weighted $MSE$.

Comment: Could you please give an example for picking $v$-functions?